How can I turn off restricted mode on YouTube on an iPad?
The option to turn off restricted mode on YouTube on my personal iPad is grayed out and it says that it is turned on by "the network administrator", but I'm using my personal network.
I have searched for ann answer on YouTube and I've Googled possible fixes to this for days, but I have found nothing.
Additional steps I have taken are:

Going into the network settings on the iPad for my personal network, deleting the automatically created DNS servers and adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google's DNS service) as my DNS servers.

Checked if anything has changed in the content restriction settings on my personal network (Xfinity). Nothing had changed and no content restrictions have been set to my knowledge.

Factory reset the iPad and erased all settings. This allowed restricted mode to be turned off by default for a while, then it automatically turned on again.

No other devices that I use on my personal network have this issue, just my iPad.

Tried connecting to my phone’s mobile hotspot. Same issue.



This could also be a Google Account setting either because of (1) corporate Google account domain settings, or (2) family settings.
Google Support's Turn Restricted Mode on or off on YouTube article links to a dedicated YouTube page for content restrictions (https://www.youtube.com/check_content_restrictions) that should explain exactly why it's restricted for you. There should be a reason on that page that lists why you're unable to disable it for yourself.

Everything on the YouTube content restriction settings is turned off.

Oh never mind. There are DNS restrictions turned on. Any ideas how I would go about getting those turned off?

I've never dealt with this problem before. I see how it's enabled ( https://support.google.com/a/answer/6214622?hl=en#zippy=%2Coption-dns ), but I don't know anything about your network/devices to know how it's being set, and for that matter how it's been overridden given your statement about changing your DNS servers. My only remaining guess is that this is being done by a local app, perhaps a "Device VPN".

Does the Youtube restricted mode stay enforced if you take the iPad to another network or location?
When it is greyed out, that it is enforced at the network level (if it was enforced at one of the other levels you could uncheck it).
Check your Xfinity "XFI" settings, and see if either "Advanced Security" or "Parental Controls" is enabled/enforced.

Does the Youtube restricted mode stay enforced if you take the iPad to another network or location?
When it is greyed out, that means that it is either enforced at the network level, so none of your settings on your local devices will do it - for example, I've seen this if you have parental controls enabled on your mobile account at your phone provider level.

It does stay enforced on other networks, yes

Then it's in your network settings on the device. Are there any configuration profiles installed (see https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/install-or-remove-configuration-profiles-iph6c493b19/ios) on the device? These enforce that.
